# Can we change colorPrimary & colorPrimaryDark programmatically according to the condition?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I'm developing an Android application in which I want to change the color scheme according the network status. For example if network connection is available the app theme will be green and if network connection is not available then it will be red.. Please ignore the action bar elevation. For example: [image][image]

Comment: No, you can't change theme attributes. Yes, you can call `toolbar.setBackgroundColor(...)` and `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(...)`.

Comment: I think you can define 2 styles where the second style has the first as a parent layout and overwrite the color only. Then you should be able to use `setTheme(int resid)` on Activity level (or in the Application using `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`) to set the color on the fly based on network status.

Answer (score 1):

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow(); window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVegItems));
}

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `Theme` programmatically, take a look at [this](https://medium.com/android-news/android-changing-app-theme-at-runtime-ab17d3eb93cc#.catnzehl1).

Comment: a) Include essential parts of linked content in your answer. This post would be useless if the author decided to pull the article. b) A better term would be "switch". You can switch between premade themes. You can't change a theme definition at runtime.